# iTunes Connect - new builds not showing up in TestFlight (Xcode 7.1)

Tags: ios, xcode, app-store-connect, testflight

I uploaded a new build last night/this morning from Xcode 7.1, and it doesn't seem to be getting put into iTunes Connect properly.  Under activity, the build is uploaded and processed but in TestFlight, no builds show up for internal users and external users don't even load (just get a spinner).  Anyone else seeing this issue?  Thanks!

[build doesn't show up for internal testers (nor do old ones)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uc2gd.png)

[external testers - just a spinner](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TUECc.png)

Comment: last night/ this mng ? what does it mean? Normally it takes 10-20 mins to get your build processed and ready for test flight!!!

Comment: @Mr.T the build is processed after 20-30min in both instances.  But then I get those linked pictures and I can't test???  In the Activity tab (not TestFlight), the build shows up (doesn't say processing) just like normal.

Comment: If it means anything at all - I tried uploading a new build from Application Loader instead of Xcode, and I still get the same problem.

Comment: SHITTY bug. Still waiting for a fix. This is pathetic

Answer (score 2):

According Apple tech support on the phone, this is a known issue they're working on which is affecting more than my account ( the builds not showing up in TestFlight, and the spinners without loading).

Comment: Its been 3 years and this is still an issue.  Come on Apple.